# MVC Action returning either Actionresult leaving the view unmodified or a View actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionresult

My problem in an **MVC Razor** application:
I use a polling controller action call based on a **javascript** timer to request if there is already an answer (which by the way happens through **WCF** in the `Controller` call).

If there is an answer, the view gets updated through a normal return `View(...)` action result, which updates the view correctly.
But if the answer is still not available, I would like an ActionResult that does not change or update the `View`. I tried to return `EmptyResult`, but then my webpage turns white. I would like not to modify my controller action call method if possible:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("actionTryGetNewSystemSentence", "Conduct", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { onsubmit = "OnTryGetNewSystemSentence(event)", id = "idConductForm" })) 
        { ...}
```

I also tried other `ActionResult` types but either they modify the view or return a blank or invalid `View`. The polling gets done every **500 ms**, so I can't let the view update every **500 ms**.

Comment: Are you trying to make an ajax Request based on timer or you are just reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are using here a **Html.BeginForm** which mean it is not a ajax call. You must specify Ajax.BeginForm and define a function in jquery that you will call when the result is success or fail and update the html accordingly.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("actionTryGetNewSystemSentence", "Conduct", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "POST", onsubmit = "OnTryGetNewSystemSentence(event)", OnSuccess = "Successmethod(event)", OnFailure = "Failuremethod(event)", id = "idConductForm" })) { ...})
```

check the link below

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems promising. I'll try that later this week.

Comment: I had still a lot of other problems, but your anwser put me in the right direction. Now I have the annoying problem that I can't refresh/reload my razor page from js.